# Update a table with the average from another table - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables (*ca* and *average_table*).

> *ca* has three columns: Group_id, Group_name, ca_value 
>   *average_table* has two columns: Group_name, ca_value

I want to calculate the ca_value average of all groups in *ca* and update *average_table* with this data.

This is what I have

```
    //create average table
$average_table="CREATE TABLE average_table(Group_name CHAR(30) Primary Key, ca_value FLOAT)";

// Execute query
if (mysql_query($average_table))
  {
  echo "Table average created successfully";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating table: " . mysql_error();
  }

//Calculate average
$ca = mysql_query("Select AVG(ca_value) FROM ca");

$data_sql = "INSERT INTO average_table (Group_name, ca_value) Values ('Average all groups',$ca)";
// Execute query
if (mysql_query($data_sql))
  {
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error Selecting group: " . mysql_error();
  }
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id #6)' at line 1

Comment: That error is not a from a query in the code above. The id column or text is not used there

Comment: I'm guessing Values can't take $ca but how do insert the query in the table?

Comment: he is not using     or die(mysql_error) in the query's above so my guess it that the error happens somewhere but but not in the code given in the op

Comment: I think $ca is Resource id #6 but I might be wrong.

Comment: Is this the complete code?

Comment: Use a view, don't use a table.

Comment: no, this isn't the complete code but the error is from this call. Should I update the question with the complete code (>600 lines of code)?

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query` returns a result resource pointer, not the actual results of the query. You have to get the results out using `mysql_fetch_array`, `mysql_fetch_assoc`, etc. Also, `mysql_*` is deprecated; please consider switching to mysqli or PDO. Per the manual at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.
>
> The returned result resource should be passed to mysql_fetch_array(), and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the returned data.